# How to use React hooks for function and pass in function as props to create generic modal?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, frontend, react-hooks

I have created a very simple modal from antd, and i want to use this basic modal as a generic modal, for many parts of my app. The thing i cant figure out though is how to first use a react hook for a function with parameters and then how i can pass that function into the modal component as props.

```
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('New Folder')
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('Untitled Folder')
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Create')
  const [submissionAction, setSubmissionAction] = useState('New Folder')

<Modal
        width={300}
        centered={true}
        visible={visible}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        footer={[
          <Button key="back" onClick={handleCancel}>
            Cancel
          </Button>,
          <Button
            key="submit"
            type="primary"
            loading={loading}
            onClick={() => {
              form
                .validateFields()
                .then((values) => {
                  console.log(values)
                  if (submissionAction === 'New Folder') {
                    createNewFolder(values.name)
                  } else if (submissionAction === 'New File') {
                    createNewFile(values.name)
                  }
                  setVisible(false)
                })
                .catch((info) => {
                  console.log('Validate Failed:', info)
                })
            }}
          >
            {buttonText}
          </Button>,
        ]}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: '16px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            paddingBottom: '15px',
            color: 'black',
          }}
        >
          {title}
        </div>
        <Form
          form={form}
          layout="vertical"
          name="form_in_modal"
          initialValues={{ name: inputValue }}
        >
          <Form.Item
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please enter a name',
              },
            ]}
            name="name"
          >
            <Input type="textarea" value={inputValue} />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
```

Notice how variables like buttonText or title are dynamic, i am using hooks for those, and later when i make this modal into a generic component i will pass in the values as props. How can i pass in the value of the functions in onClick as props though? And how would i even store them using state to begin with?

Like instead of using a string (submissionAction) to represent which function to call, say I had a hook for the function, so when a user clicks a button to create a new folder, i will set the value of that hook to be the corresponding function createNewFolder, otherwise createNewFile or editFolder etc. Then I will pass the value of this hook into a generic modal component, so that i can reuse it all across my app. How can i do this? Or is there a better way to do what i'm trying to achieve. Do i need to create a modal component in each component where im using a modal or can i have one modal used across all?

Comment: Your generic modal should just do the rendering part. Say that you'll have a `submitText` props and `onSubmit` props. Then your parent component will do the complex logic when `onSubmit` is triggered.

Comment: Youre saying my modal will have submitText and onSubmit props? How would i trigger the parent functions from inside the generic modal component? I am realising the major issue with my problem is modal accessibility, what if i want to access the modal from another component, Ill have to create a new one? For example for every component that has an edit functionality, for an edit button in the component onClick i would want to show the modal and then do the function, how can i access the modal in all my components?

Comment: I think you are making your Modal component too complicated. The complex logic should be done in your parent component, say that you have a function called `handleModalOnSubmit` that handles either `createNewFolder`, or `createNewFile` or whatever, you can just render it like `<Modal onSubmit={this.handleModalOnSubmit} />`. Then whenever your modal is submitted it will trigger that function which does the complex logic. Since your modal is triggering an `onSubmit` callback everytime it is submitted, you can pass in different `onSubmit` handler for different purposes, making your modal generic.

Comment: Okay, that is a good point, i tried it now but all that does is abstract the logic from the modal to outside which DOES make more sense. However, do you know how i can change the state of the function that needs execution? Like the submissionAction, i dont like how im setting the state to a string and then checking all possible strings and then calling the corresponding function. Is there a way you know of where when a user say clicks to create a new file, I am able to set the state to be that function, with the required parameter?

Comment: Also while this does make it cleaner, it doesnt solve the accessibility issue. Do you know how can i access this modal from other components? Do i need to create a new modal component in each case? Like say my folder component has an icon to edit the folder, how can i access the modal from inside of that component without needing to create a new one?